# Derivative of a tensor operation

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm reading a book on deep learning and I'm a bit confused about one of the ideas the author mentioned.

I don't understand why we subtract -step * gradient (f) (W0) from the weight and not just -step, since -step * gradient (f) (W0) represents a loss while -step is the parameter (i.e the x value i.e small change in weight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient tell you which **direction** to move and the step would help to control the magnitude that you move so that your sequence converges.

We can't just subtract `step`. Recall that `step` is just a scalar number. `W0` is a tensor. We can't subtract a tensor by a scalar number. The gradient is a tensor with the same size as `W0` and that would make the subtraction well defined.

Readings on [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) might help your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the parameter opposite to its gradient by a small amount to make sure the loss goes down. Using just `step` does not guarantee that the loss decreases. This is called gradient descent in optimization and there is proof of convergence. You can check online tutorials on this topic such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent).